# Ajax get Request returns "Unauthorized" for Azure Ad Graph API

Tags: ajax, azure, typescript, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to call the `Azure Ad Graph API` from my `typescript` code, but I keep getting the error: `Unauthorized`

```
lavaNET.SharePointREST.getJsonWithoutSite(this, "https://graph.windows.net/lavanet.dk/users?api-version=1.6", (tmplData: any, tmplTextStatus: string, tmplXHR: JQueryXHR) => {
    console.log(tmplData)
});

export function getJsonWithoutSite(context: any, url: string, success: SuccessCallback, failure?: ErrorCallback) {

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        context: context,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer zc21eb27-760b-4b46-828e-xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        accepts: { json: 'application/json; odata=verbose' },
        success: success,
        error: failure || function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Error: ' + errorThrown); }
    });
}
```

Can someone Point out why I can't get the data from the Ad?

**Update** Is this what i need or am i totally wrong: [image]

**Update** In reply to `Gary Liu - MSFT`, I get these keys from hes code: [image]

Is my Ajax correct and what key should i use?

Comment: Because there is no access token in the headers, just "Bearer"?

Comment: I cant seem to find anyway to get the token. I spend all day reading the guides i can find but unable to find anywhere i can get the token, do you have an idea or link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have generate an access token, and set it in `Authorization` header.

We need to manually follow the [OAuth 2.0 authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) to implement the functionality to acquire access token from Azure AD in our application.

Also you can leverage ADAL SDK to implement this functionality in your app with an ease. However, currently there is no such ADAL for ts existed. You can try to leverage [ADAL for js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to grand access token, store it in session Storage or local Storage in client browsers. And use the token in your ts scripts.

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js) for how to use ADAL for js in plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gary, But i still get unauthorized when i try with some of the tokens i get from your code. I updated my quest, and i would love it you would read the last update section

Comment: according your last capture, it seems that you have successfully acquired the access token. However, according to your code snippet, you maybe used the wrong token. The correct access token should be a JWT, which is like `eyJxxx.eyJyyy.eyJzzzz`. You can try to use `getCachedToken()` in SDK, see the source code at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L304